# IIS URL Redirect change querystring parameter name

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I am trying to redirect from one site to another like the following.

```
http://example.com/quickscan/?code=123456
```

To

```
https://example2.com/as-quickscan/login?username=123456
```

> The domains are different. Also the redirect URL parameter and URL structure is entirely different.

What I have tried is the following and some other variations.

```
<rule name="Redirect quickscan" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^quickscan/\?[a-zA-Z]+=([0-9]+)?$" ignoreCase="true" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://example2.com/as-quickscan/login?username={R:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>
```

```
<rule name="Redirect quickscan" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^quickscan/\?[a-zA-Z]+?=([0-9]+)?$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://example2.com/as-quickscan/login?username={R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed. I used the following.

```
<rule name="Redirect quickscan" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^quickscan/" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="([a-z]+)=([0-9]+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://example2.com/as-quickscan/login?username={C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```